# Convergence of a Sequence question

Tags: real-analysis

I am doing revision and just wanted to ask if this is okay,

Question:Prove $5-\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges to 5 using the epsilon proof of a convergence.

My Attempt let: $ \epsilon>0 $ be given. I then proceed as follows
 $|5-\frac{1}{n^2}-5|<\epsilon$.  I solve the contents in |abs| to get $|\frac{5n^2-1-5n^2}{5}|<\epsilon$ further simplifying to get $|\frac{-1}{5}|<\epsilon$. The absolute value disappears to get $1/5<\epsilon$ to which I take the reciprocal and end up with this $5>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: $|5-\frac{1}{n^2}-5|$ is not equal to 1/5 but to $\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: thank you, yes you are right, I realized the mistake, $|\frac{5n^2-1-5n^2}{n^2}|$ instead of 5 as denominator.

Answer (score 1):

If you correct the mistake mentioned in the comments, this problem reduces to showing that there is some $N$ for which 
$$
|\frac{1}{n^2}|<\epsilon
$$
for some given epsilon and any $n>N$.

You can solve for this $N$ in terms of epsilon:
$$
\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon\implies\ n^2>\frac{1}{\epsilon}\implies n>\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}
$$
So take $N=\lceil\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}\rceil$ and you will have the required inequality.

Comment: yes you are right, I made the mistake where I have 5 as the denominator I should have $n^2$